# ACPI Error when booting, Can't Boot

Tags: dual-boot, acpi, 23.04

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 on my LG Gram laptop (in dual boot with Windows 11) after several reboots, it shows me an error when booting that does not let me continue with the boot. This is what it shows me

[image: this is what it shows me]

I have searched in forums, and it seems that everyone who has had this happen can continue booting, but this is not my case.

Some of the checks I have done:

- According to the LG utility, the BIOS is updated to the latest version.
- I ran the check tests that I can access from the boot menu, all of them were satisfactory.
- I tried modifying GRUB options.
- I disabled RTD3 in the BIOS.
- I tried reinstalling Ubuntu (I deleted everything and did a fresh install).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it. It was corrupted gdm.

It had nothing to do with these ACPI errors. These errors are just warnings, but you can get rid of them by

`rmmod int3403_thermal`

Anyway, to find a cause you need to press ctrl-alt-F2 to get into a shell, the by using `journalctl` locate a reason why boot failed.

Good luck!